# Assignments in conditions

Tags: python, syntax, variable-assignment

In C-like languages, we can write a loop like that:

```
while ( a = func(x) ){
    // use a
}
```

Is there any syntax in Python to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent because [assignments are statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt) in Python, not expressions like in C.

Instead, you can do either this:

```
a = func(x)      # Assign a
while a:         # Loop while a is True
    # use a
    a = func(x)  # Re-evaluate a
```

or this:

```
while True:      # Loop continuously
    a = func(x)  # Assign a
    if not a:    # Check if a is True
        break    # Break if not
    # use a
```

The first solution is less code, but I personally prefer the second because it keeps you from duplicating the `a = func(x)` line.

Answer (score 0):

No python does not have this because you open yourself up to bugs like

```
if usr = 'adminsitrator':
    # do some action only administrators can do
```

Where you really meant `==` and not `=`

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't allow assignments in the place of boolean expressions. The "pythonic" way to do this would be:

```
def func(x):
    if goodStuff:
        return somethingTruthy
    else:
        return somethingFalsey

a = func(x)
while a:
    # use a
    a = func(x)
```